# SQLAlchemy+Postgres - using generated sequential id without a flush

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy with Postgres and need to create "external ids" that depend on the Postgres-generated (sequential) id. The code looks like this:

```
# session is passed to the constructor as described in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it
def make_merchant(merchant_data, session):
    merchant = Merchant(**merchant_data)
    session.add(merchant)
    session.flush()   # Is this needed to have Postgres generate the sequential id?
    merchant.external_id = 'merchant_' + convert_to_external_id(merchant.id)   # Uses the Postgres-generated id
```

My issue: the flush seems necessary to get the Postgres-generated id, but it introduces a potentially annoying side effect as it flushes not only the newly created merchant but also other objects in the session.

My questions:

- Is there a way to access the Postgres id without a flush?
- If not, is there a way to only flush this one object? Creating a separate session just for this construction seems like an anti-pattern

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Louis. I'm not familiar with SQLAlchemy, but in postgres you can access the current value of a sequence with the function `currval('seq_name')`.

Comment: first question: no.  
second: 
I don't quite understand what you mean by other objects in the session, though. What other objects and how are they in your session without your knowledge?

Comment: @joppich the make_merchant function, when called, is given a session object created somewhere else. That way, this function and other similar ones can be called multiple times within the same session. So, other objects may have been added to the session before the function executes. The alternative is to create a session and commit it within the function, but that creates many transactions and you have to reattach objects manually in the caller code, see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it

Comment: [`Session.flush([objects])`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.flush), where objects is an optional set of objects to restrict the flush to, but it comes with a bit of a warning, which you should read and think if this perhaps is an XY problem. Why does it matter if you flush the other changes?

Comment: Thanks @IljaEverilä that's what I need - and it seems this is the exact usecase for it; I think most of the times I won't care when I flush but I want to avoid side effects whenever I can.